# curl url(custum port) html grab show blank on live site php

Tags: php, xml, url, curl, request

I want to grab html of URL with custom port(instead of 8080) i.e abc.com:1234 but its shows blank on live server but works fine on localhost

My Code:

```
     <?php ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

                        ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true); ini_set('allow_url_include', true); ini_set('allow_url_include', 'on'); ?> 

                    <?php 
 //getSslPage("http://portquiz.net:8080"); 
         getSslPage("http://portquiz.net:666");         

                function getSslPage($url) { 
         $curl_connection =   curl_init($url); 
        //set options ///
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3990);

                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,   "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");

                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                             'Content-Type: text/xml',
                            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                            'Keep-Alive: 300' ));

                        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0); 
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); //old value 15 

            //set data to be posted 
            //curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
            //perform our request  
            $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);  
            echo "<h1 style=color:blue>Output Result:</h1><br>"; 
             echo htmlentities($result);  
             echo "<h1 style=color:blue>|Curl Exec Detail:</h1><br>"; 
             //var_dump($result); 
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));   
            echo "</pre>";  
             echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '<br/>';
             echo curl_error($curl_connection) . '<br/>';




                        } exit; ?>
```

Output on Localhost:

```
Output Result:

<html> <head> <title>Outgoing Port Tester</title> <style type="text/css"> body { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em; } </style> </head> <body> <h1>Outgoing port tester</h1> This server listens on all TCP ports, allowing you to test any outbound TCP port. <p> You have reached this page on port <b>666</b>.<br/> </p> Your network allows you to use this port. (Assuming that your network is not doing advanced traffic filtering.) <p> Network service: unknown<br/> Your outgoing IP: 39.32.94.166</p> <h2>Test a port using a command</h2> <pre> $ telnet portquiz.net 666 Trying ... Connected to portquiz.net. Escape character is '^]'. </pre> <pre> $ nc -v portquiz.net 666 Connection to portquiz.net 666 port [tcp/daytime] succeeded! </pre> <pre> $ curl portquiz.net:666 Port 666 test successful! Your IP: 39.32.94.166</pre> <pre> $ wget -qO- portquiz.net:666 Port 666 test successful! Your IP: 39.32.94.166</pre> <pre> # For Windows PowerShell users PS C:\&gt; Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel detailed -ComputerName portquiz.net -Port 666</pre> <h2>Test a port using your browser</h2> <p> In your browser address bar: <strong>http://portquiz.net:XXXX</strong> </p> Examples: <br/> <a href="http://portquiz.net:8080">http://portquiz.net:8080</a> <br/> <a href="http://portquiz.net:8">http://portquiz.net:8</a> <br/> <a href="http://portquiz.net:666">http://portquiz.net:666</a> <br/> <p> I got complains that portquiz is not working on port 445. My hosting company OVH is probably blocking this port. Sorry about that. Feel free to contact them. See <a href="http://positon.org/is-ovh-blocking-port-445">my blog post</a> and <a href="https://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php/106901-OVH-bloque-le-port-445-vers-mon-serveur-d%C3%A9di%C3%A9">OVH forum post (french)</a>. </p> <p> Your browser can block network ports normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. In this case you should use the telnet or netcat commands to test the port. </p> <p> Please also note that this server uses some port for real services (22, 25), so testing with your browser on those ports will not work. </p> <p> <i>Contact/feedback:</i><br/> <img src="portquizm.png" /> </p> <p> <i>See also:</i><br/> <ul> <li> <a href="http://en.positon.org/post/An-outgoing-port-tester">Blog post on this topic</a> and <a href="http://positon.org/portquiz-net-how-it-works">How it works</a> </li> <li> <a href="http://www.firebind.com/">Firebind</a>, a commercial tester. <a href="http://www.firebind.com/clients/web/">javascript test</a> </li> <li> <a href="https://github.com/nhooyr/outPorts">outPorts</a>, a tiny program to test a range of ports using portquiz </li> </ul> </p> </body> </html>
|Curl Exec Detail:

Array
(
    [url] => http://portquiz.net:666/
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 233
    [request_size] => 184
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.5
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.234
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.234
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 2694
    [speed_download] => 5388
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 2694
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.5
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 178.33.250.62
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 666
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.47
    [local_port] => 54754
)

0
```

Output on Live Site:(result show blank/Empty)

```
Output Result:

|Curl Exec Detail:

Array
(
    [url] => http://portquiz.net:666/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 19.340628
    [namelookup_time] => 0.117558
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)

28
Connection timed out after 20001 milliseconds
```

Please Help me i am working it from last 2 days but no success thanks

Comment: can you check server firewall if its blocking the url?

Comment: my all other curl script are working also i seen in phpinfo() curl is enabled,i tested this script on different hosting server but shows same result

Comment: error_code 0 mostly indicates you cannot connect to the remote host. So this might be a firewall issue

Comment: but @tlenss its work fine on localhost if it has firewall issue then how its baypass on localhost

Comment: Maybe the network your server is on does not allow traffic over port 666. Maybe it does not allow traffic to that specific site. Have you tried wget or curl (or the methods @Ivan Yarych suggested) from the server to the site in question?

Comment: it show bool(false) but why its show same bool false for my 2nd site server what every server block permission and also is any way to open it and i am surprise why this site open in html frame on hosting server if is any permission also how third party site origin able to grab all html demo link(please remove sapce ahead "http" before open link) http :// alloworigin.com/get?url=http :// portquiz.net:666 also it can view in browser and html frame

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted above i saw no curl_exec, so i added that.

This works for me:

```
<?php ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);
ini_set('allow_url_include', true);
ini_set('allow_url_include', 'on');
?>

<?php

//getSslPage("http://portquiz.net:8"); 
function getSslPage($url) {
    $curl_connection = curl_init($url); //set options ///curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3990);

    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");

    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'Keep-Alive: 300'));

    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); //old value 15 //set data to be posted //curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); //perform our request  $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);  echo "<h1 style=color:blue>Output Result:</h1><br>";  echo htmlentities($result);   echo "<h1 style=color:blue>|Curl Exec Detail:</h1><br>";  //var_dump($result);  echo "<pre>";
    echo "</pre>";
    echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_error($curl_connection) . '<br/>';

    print_r(curl_exec($curl_connection));

    print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
}

getSslPage("http://portquiz.net:666");
```

result:

```
</pre>0<br/><br/>
<html>
<head>
<title>Outgoing Port Tester</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Outgoing port tester</h1>

This server listens on all TCP ports, allowing you to test any outbound TCP port.

<p>
You have reached this page on port <b>666</b>.<br/>
</p>

Your network allows you to use this port.
(Assuming that your network is not doing advanced traffic filtering.)

<p>
Network service: unknown<br/>
Your outgoing IP: 131.228.182.254</p>

<h2>Test a port using a command</h2>

<pre>
$ telnet portquiz.net 666 
Trying ...
Connected to portquiz.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
</pre>
<pre>
$ nc -v portquiz.net 666 
Connection to portquiz.net 666 port [tcp/daytime] succeeded!
</pre>
<pre>
$ curl portquiz.net:666 
Port 666 test successful!
Your IP: 131.228.182.254</pre>
<pre>
$ wget -qO- portquiz.net:666 
Port 666 test successful!
Your IP: 131.228.182.254</pre>
<pre>
# For Windows PowerShell users
PS C:\&gt; Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel detailed -ComputerName portquiz.net -Port 666</pre>

<h2>Test a port using your browser</h2>

<p>
In your browser address bar: <strong>http://portquiz.net:XXXX</strong>
</p>

Examples: <br/>
<a href="http://portquiz.net:8080">http://portquiz.net:8080</a> <br/>
<a href="http://portquiz.net:8">http://portquiz.net:8</a> <br/>
<a href="http://portquiz.net:666">http://portquiz.net:666</a> <br/>

<p>
I got complains that portquiz is not working on port 445. My hosting company OVH is probably blocking this port. Sorry about that. Feel free to contact them. See <a href="http://positon.org/is-ovh-blocking-port-445">my blog post</a> and <a href="https://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php/106901-OVH-bloque-le-port-445-vers-mon-serveur-d%C3%A9di%C3%A9">OVH forum post (french)</a>.
</p>

<p>
Your browser can block network ports normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. In this case you should use the telnet or netcat commands to test the port.
</p>
<p>
Please also note that this server uses some port for real services (22, 25), so testing with your browser on those ports will not work.
</p>


<p>
<i>Contact/feedback:</i><br/>
<img src="portquizm.png" />
</p>

<p>
<i>See also:</i><br/>
<ul>
<li> <a href="http://en.positon.org/post/An-outgoing-port-tester">Blog post on this topic</a> and <a href="http://positon.org/portquiz-net-how-it-works">How it works</a> </li>
<li> <a href="http://www.firebind.com/">Firebind</a>, a commercial tester. <a href="http://www.firebind.com/clients/web/">javascript test</a> </li>
<li> <a href="https://github.com/nhooyr/outPorts">outPorts</a>, a tiny program to test a range of ports using portquiz </li>
</ul>
</p>

</body>

</html>
Array
(
    [url] => http://portquiz.net:666/
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 233
    [request_size] => 184
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.054183
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004118
    [connect_time] => 0.024217
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.024252
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 2703
    [speed_download] => 49886
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 2703
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.053941
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 178.33.250.62
    [certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

    [primary_port] => 666
    [local_ip] => 10.223.128.174
    [local_port] => 36696
)
```

Comment: i think you are running on localhost for localhost my code also working
your code result is same for live site:
Output:
0

Array ( [url] => http://portquiz.net:666/ [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 19.492068 [namelookup_time] => 0.274412 [connect_time] => 0 .......

Comment: [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 )

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine to me, as a workaround try changing :

`curl_setopt ( $curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );`

to

`curl_setopt ( $curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );`

As described in the Return Values section of curl-exec PHP manual page: http://php.net/manual/function.curl-exec.php

You should enable the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option for redirects but this would be a problem if your server is in safe_mode and/or open_basedir is in effect which can cause issues with curl as well.

Comment: Can you confirm the following :
1) PHP version ?
2) Curl Version ?
3) open_basedir values ?
4) safe_mode value ?

Comment: PHP version:5.6.16
Curl Version: 7.38.0 
open_basedir values: no value
sql.safe_mode : Off
by the why i try same script on different server but it shows same result i think i have code problem because how third party site origin able to grab all html demo link(please remove sapce ahead "http" before open link) http :// alloworigin.com/get?url=http :// portquiz.net:666 also it can view in browser and html frame

Answer (score 0):

The important message here is:

> Connection timed out after 20001 milliseconds

It means your connection didn't go through to that host. The reason maybe a firewall or network misconfiguration on either end - your server or remote server.

The first thing that comes to my mind is port number (666) that is lower than 1024. On Unix systems only privileged users can listen to those ports. So if you are using regular user you could be unable to listen to it.

But if you are able to connect to it from your local machine the problem is probably is with your server. In order to check if it is configured to pass connections to any port you can try this simple command in your terminal:

```
$ telnet portquiz.net 666
Trying 178.33.250.62...
Connected to portquiz.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
```

`GET /` is HTTP request you need to enter from keyboard if/when you get the prompt. If you don't get the prompt and you get timeout message after some time - your host is configured to not pass connections to custom ports. This is often the issue with shared hosting.

In such a case you should do one of the following:

- reconfigure your host to allow such connections
- use some standard port: 80, 8080, 443, etc
- switch your hosting provider to the one that doesn't have such restrictions.

**EDIT:** You can also do a simple check from your PHP script:

```
$fp = fsockopen("portquiz.net", 666);
var_dump($fp);
```

If result of `var_dump` is `false` or you get a timeout executing that page - the reason is connecting to random ports is not permitted on your hosting.

Comment: i test my code on other hosting server and also on phpfiddler but no success if its firewall or premission issue then why this third party site origin able to grab all html demo link(please remove sapce ahead "http" before open link)
http :// alloworigin.com/get?url=http :// portquiz.net:666
also it can view in browser and html frame

Comment: Have you tried connecting with `telnet portquiz.net 666` ?

Comment: No, you can not do that from cPanel, you can do it also from a simple PHP script - see my updated answer

Comment: yup ivan it show bool(false) but why its show same bool false for my 2nd site server what every server block permission and also is any way to open it and i am surprise why this site open in html frame on hosting server if is any permission also how third party site origin able to grab all html demo link(please remove sapce ahead "http" before open link) http :// alloworigin.com/get?url=http :// portquiz.net:666 also it can view in browser and html frame

Comment: Most (if not all) shared hosting providers block all ports communication except the standard ones. The reason is they want to prevent malware spread that was intentionally or unintentionally installed on their accounts.
If you want to use custom ports you should switch to VPS hosting - it allows you do much more, but requires more knowledge to maintain.
Also you can contact your hosting provider regarding those issues - maybe they have plans that permit using custom ports.

Comment: i have low budget hosting so this hosting server package is best for me they are not taking risk because i am using shared hosting site  that why i am thinking any hacking method which can archive my goal and no need to change my hosting server

Comment: In that case consider using standard ports

Comment: i cant because this is testing url(portquiz.net:666) i am working on API which URL has port till now my success is that i am using alloworigin thrid party which allow me to access anysite html without any port limitation but i think this is not good to send my personal api data on third party so i am still working on this problem for making own custom code instead of allow-origin API

Comment: There is no other option. Either enable communications on non-standard ports (switch plan or hosting) or use standard ports. Sorry

Comment: thxs ivan but after my curl and php research i will move forward to ajax and frame bcuase now frame show anysite with any port so i will url on frame after that i will search any method which will gave me frame code i dont know its will help me or it just waste of time let see

Answer (score 0):

Note that `curl_*` functions in PHP are **wrapper of curl program.**

It means you can try same thing via command line.

If you can connect your live server via SSH or Telnet,

Try `curl http://portquiz.net:666 -v` and see what the real problem is.

Answer (score -2):

Have you noticed this error "Connection timed out after 20001 milliseconds"

Increase your Connection time out time here add enough time instead of 20

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
```

Comment: no success i set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT as 0,1,15,20,400 but no success with anyone :(

Comment: `code` curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); still no success